# Get JSON Value Type C# Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, types, json.net

After deserializing a JSON string with:

```
dynamic objJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJSON)
```

I am able to loop through and access names and values using .Name and .Value properties.

But, how can I determine the type of the data? (e.g. I would like to know if a piece of data has been deserialized as a string or as a date or as an integer)

---

Edited to add context:

The short story is that I my JSON source may extend later (more fields) and the database insert I'm doing will need to include the extensions. I would prefer not to have to come back and edit this part of code later, too easy to forget, so I'm building a dynamic database insert by scrutinizing data types. The names of the fields in the JSON data coorrelate exactly to the field names in my database... so I want to scrutinize the datatype and build a DB insert flow accordingly.

Comment: Note that usually it is other way around - you know what type it is and ask for `Value<int>`... Details of your actual case why you need that may help with finding good answer.

Comment: JSON doesn't store the type of your object. It only makes a difference between boolean and numbers. Everything else is store as a string

Comment: You're right... I can't do it this way because sometimes I will have a NULL for the value... no way JSON would be able to tell me the datatype of the actual field (e.g. integer) when there's just a NULL to go on.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, I can't expect JSON to give me datatypes in the way I need. An obvious example is if I have a NULL value in the data... how could it possible tell me that the data type behind the scenes is an integer.

I will add another layer to fetch the data structure of the SQL table and then pull the data type from that when looping through fields.